# Can't scandir() in php referenced from root Centos 7 using apache

Tags: php, apache, centos7, selinux, scandir

After reading lots of questions regarding php scandir() I haven't found one that answered my question. If this is a duplicate, please let me know where the answer is before marking me down.

**Problem:**

If I do

```
var_dump(scandir("/"));
```

Then I get the contents of the system root folder: bin, installs, nvme, var, etc, etc...

If I do

```
var_dump(scandir("/nvme"));
```

Then I get false and an error that var/www/public_html/nvme doesn't exist.

So then if I do

```
var_dump(scandir("../../../../../../../"));
```

I can see the system root folder

but if I do

```
var_dump(scandir("../../../../../../../nvme"));
```

then I get a permission denied error.

I tested that I can scan each directory between the public_html and the root directory, but the moment I try to scan forward a directory then I run into errors. All the directories on the way back are owned by the same user as the nvme directory I'm trying to scan. Using file_get_contents throws the same error.

In SElinux I gave apache permission to read and write to the nvme folder. I'm running on Centos 7 with SElinux enabled.

Why can't I can a up from root on a different directory path?

**EDIT:**

My specific error was that I hadn't completed setting the SElinux context.

Previously I had run
     `semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t "/nvme(/.*)`

but after that I still needed to run
     `restorecon -v "/nvme"`

so that the new context was actually implemented. Now `var_dump(scandir("/./nvme"));` and `var_dump(scandir("../../../../../../../nvme"));` both work.

Comment: try `/./nvme` maybe? See [`chroot`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chroot.php) also.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just learned that I don't have chroot. `scandir('/./nvme')` still gives the same error.

Comment: Are you thinking it might be SElinux? I blush to say I disable that entirely on web servers. Can you turn it off a sec to test if that is the issue? Not saying you have to leave it off. `setenforce 0`

Comment: That was the first thing I thought, so I set `semanage fcontext -a -t http_sys_content_t "/nvme"` but it still didn't work. When I setenforce 0 then it worked, so you've narrowed it down to selinux.

Comment: And this is where I bow out :) I've read up on it but still have never managed to get a frontend server to actually work with SELinux enabled... `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` ? httpd vs http? `-Z` flag on `ls` is your friend

Comment: After running the semanage utility as shown in the comment above, I needed to run `restorecon -v "/nvme"`. I thought I had, but apparently I didn't. Having rerun the specific SElinux steps, now I've got it working. Thanks again. If you make it an answer, I'd be glad to check it.